# What will be the output from the following three code segments?

Tags: java, string, pool

I'm currently on a self learning course for Java and have gotten completely stumped at one of the questions and was wonder if anyone can help me see sense...

Question: What will be the output from the following three code segments? Explain fully the differences.

```
public static void method2(){ 

    String mystring1 = "Hello World"; 

    String mystring2 = new String("Hello World"); 

    if (mystring1.equals(mystring2)) { 

        System.out.println("M2 The 2 strings are equal"); 

    } else { 

        System.out.println("M2 The 2 strings are not equal"); 

    } 

}

public static void method3(){ 

    String mystring1 = "Hello World"; 

    String mystring2 = "Hello World"; 

    if (mystring1 == mystring2) { 

        System.out.println("M3 The 2 strings are equal"); 

    } else { 

        System.out.println("M3 The 2 strings are not equal"); 

    } 

}
```

The answer I gave:

Method 2:
    "M2 The 2 strings are equal"
It returns equal because even though they are two separate strings the (mystring1.equals(mystring2)) recognises that the two strings have the exact same value. If == was used here it return as not equal because they are two different objects.

Method 3:
    "M2 The 2 strings are equal"
The 2 strings are equal because they are both pointing towards the exact same string in the pool. == was used here making it look at the two values and it recognises that they both have the exact same characters. It recognises that Hello World was already in the pool so it points myString2 towards that string.

I was pretty confident in my answer but it's wrong. Any help?

Comment: Have you executed it?

Comment: `== was used here making it look at the two values and it recognises that they both have the exact same characters.` Wrong

Comment: This seriously is the worst quality of answers ive ever seen on SO. To all the answer autors: How about you go deeper? How about talking about String pooling in detail? How about the behaviour in different VMs? How about the difference of initializing a String with = "value", = new String("value") and = new String(new char[]{'a','b','c'}. What about oracle telling you = "a" is the same like = new String(new char[]{'a'}) but the == comparison differs with both initialisations? HOW ABOUT SO QUALITY!?

Comment: There's no point in repeating the same detailed information that has been given in many other questions already. OP has shown he understands all that (for the most part) already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both will return true.

1) 2 new string objects are created but use `.equals` which means their actual value is compared. Which is equal.

2) 1 new string object is created because they are both constant at compile time. This will result in them pointing to the same object.

This sentence might be your issue:

> == was used here making it look at the two values and it recognises that they both have the exact same characters.

`==` checks for reference equality whereas you're describing value equality.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I understand where I went wrong in method 3. However, I'm being told method 2 is completely wrong and I just can't see it.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your explanation of the first method,  I suggest you ask the TA for clarification.

Comment: I dont see any problem as well but be aware that none of all those answers included enoth deep background information of the String pooling and that there could be cases which the "yeah i know this in general" knowledge has lacks your TA wants to make you aware of ;)

Answer (score 0):

First two are equal, second two are not. But unless you put it into main() method there will be no output at all.

EDIT: second pair are not the same because "==" compares addresses in memory.

Answer (score 0):

You're right about the first one.
However the second would return "M3 The 2 strings are not equal".
This is because == tests for reference equality and since they are two different variables, they would not equal.